# Does internal energy depend only on temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, temperature, ideal-gas, gas

In isothermal expansion of an ideal gas, $ \Delta U=0$ because there is no change in temperature.

But at 290K, if we compare the internal energies of Nitrogen, Neon and Ozone, Ozone has maximum internal energy even if the temperature remains constant.

What is happening here?

Comment: Real gases are not ideal gases

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent , so $\Delta U=0$ at constant temperature is true for ideal gases *only?*

Comment: At some point in the standard introduction to statistical thermodynamics, you can derive the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The internal energy of ideal gas can be obtained from the following expression:

$$du = c_{V} d T\tag{1} $$

where $$c_{v}=\frac{f}{2}R.\tag{2}$$

In the equation $(2)$, $f$ represents the degrees of freedom of the molecule of the gas and $R$ is the ideal gas constant.

Ozone, $O3$ is a triatomic gas so it has $6$ degrees of freedom, three axes of translation and three ways to rotate.

So amongst your gases, Ozone has the highest $f$ and it has the highest internal energy at given temperature.

Btw, you can approximate some gases to obey the ideal gas law, but by no means all.

Comment: Bardo gives the correct answer again.

Answer (score 1):

Internal energy U depends on temperature, volume (e.g., specific volume) or pressure, chemical bond energies, and phase.  So different chemical species have different internal energies (and heat capacities); and, as pressure increases, spcidic volume decreases, which affects the potential energy interactions of molecules (and thus internal energy).  And, when you go from a liquid to a vapor at constant temperature, internal energy increases.